# How to handle `any` in Yup?

Tags: yup

Suppose I want the equivalent of this interface in a Yup schema:

```js
interface MyThing {
  name: string;
  other: any;
}
```

how would I deal with the `any`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `yup.mixed().nullable()` effectively serves as `any`.  So you can do:

```js
const MySchema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  other: yup.mixed().nullable(),
});
```

I tested anything passes validation for `other`, including numbers, strings, objects, `null` and `undefined`.

This also works with `InferType`:

```js
type MyType = yup.InferType<typeof MySchema>;

const myVar: MyType = {
  name: "alice",
  other: 5,
}
```